# Grails dynamic finder methods on domain classes not visible across plugin projects

Tags: grails, grails-orm

My development environment is as follows:

Grails version: 1.3.7.RELEASE

Follow the steps below:

1. `mkdir GrailsProjects`
2. `cd GrailsProjects`
3. `grails create-plugin grails-domain`
4. `cd grails-domain`
5. `grails create-domain-class Book`
6. `cd ..`
7. `grails create-plugin grails-service`
8. `cd grails-service`
9. `grails create-service BookService`
10. Add

    > ```
    > grails.plugin.location."grails-domain" = "../grails-domain"
    > ```

    at the top of the file `BuildConfig.groovy` in the `grails-service` project
11. Using a text editor, change the content of the file `Book.groovy` to:

    > ```
    > package grails.domain
    >
    > class Book {
    >     String name
    >
    >     static constraints = {
    >     }
    > }
    > ```
12. Change the content of the file `BookService.groovy` to:

    > ```
    > package grails.service
    >
    > import grails.domain.Book
    >
    > class BookService {
    >     static transactional = true
    >
    >     def someMethod() {
    >         def book = Book.findByName("Fooled by randomness")
    >     }
    > }
    > ```

On trying to call the method `BookService.someMethod`, Grails is unable to find the `findByName` method on `Book`.  `Book.name` is visible inside `BookService.someMethod`, which indicates that the `grails-service` plugin project is able to resolve the code in the `grails-domain` plugin project.

The steps are exactly as listed above; no additional steps have been performed.

Is this expected behaviour with Grails plugin projects?  Is there a different way to separate domain and service classes with Grails?

Comment: I followed your steps line by line.  In addition, I added a controller in grails-service so that I could easily call my service method via run-app.  I did a run-app from the grails-service plugin and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @david.  I had not reached a point where the plugins were integrated with a web app so I had not tested with controllers.  I was merely trying to test the concept of plugins using unit tests.  I was invoking `BookService.someMethod` from `BookServiceTests` that was created automatically when I created the service.

I found out that the domain classes have to be mocked during unit testing in order to get all the GORM functionality, including the dynamic finders.  I added `mockDomain(Book, [])` to `BookServiceTests.setUp` to get the unit tests working.

Things are working fine for me now.

Comment: If using Grails 2.0, use `@Mock` annotation.